# How to calculate the number of nights between two dates using AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to find the number of nights between two dates, couldn't find anywhere. Please help me with the shortest code snippet which will give the number of nights between two dates. For example, if two dates are - 18/10/2016 and 21/10/2016(Please consider the default time format i.e $scope.date = new date()) then the number of nights will be - 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Date is formatted as `mm/dd/yyy`

```js
var date1 = new Date("10/18/2016");
var date2 = new Date("10/21/2016");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var numberOfNights = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 

console.log(numberOfNights + " nights");
```

It also works with daylight saving days (31th march)

```js
var date1 = new Date("03/29/2016");
var date2 = new Date("04/01/2016");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var numberOfNights = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 

console.log(numberOfNights + " nights");
```

**Note**

If you are handling dates many times inside your code you may check [momentJS](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Simple One. Thanks.

Comment: I think this may not work as expected depending on your OS timezone, since if there is a daylight saving shift in time, some dates may have 25 or 23 effective hours in them. Possibly telling `Date` constructor that the passed date string is UTC somehow could do the trick...

Comment: @ArturKlesun I added an example with daylight saving and it works